# Full directed graph colored in two colors

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I was given a full directed connected graph $G$ which it's edges are colored in two colors: red and blue.

I was asked to prove that the subgraph that contains all of the nodes and only one of the colored edges is  connected (it can be weakly or strongly connected), but I got stuck in the process. Any help will do!

Comment: what do you mean by full directed graph? do you take all edges in all directions?

Comment: Weakly or strongly connected?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what do you mean by weakly?

Comment: @Lola What do you mean by [connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedDigraph.html) for a directed graph? - I chose weakly connectd for my answer - because that wrks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry but what is the differenct between the two? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the red subgraph is not strongly connected, i.e., there are two vertices $a,b$ such that there is no red path from $a$ to $b$. Then in paricular the edge $a\to b$ is blue. For any other vertex, at least one of $a\to c$, $c\to b$ is blue, hence $c$ is weakly connected to $a$ via blue edges: $c\to b\leftarrow a$ or $c\leftarrow a$. We conclude that the blue subgraph is weakly connected.

---

If we ask for strongly instead of weakly connected, this need not be the case: In $G$, pick any two vertices $a,b$, colour each edge staring in $a$ and/or ending in $b$ red and each edge starting in $b$ and/or ending in $a$ blue and colour all other edges arbitrarily. Then the red subgraph is not strongly connected because there is no red path $b\to\ldots \to a$, and the blue subgraph is not strongly connected because there is no blue path $a\to\ldots\to b$.

Comment: What is x exactly?:)

Comment: @Lola x is the key to the left of c on my keyboard :)

Comment: Amazing! thank you very much :)